# Karma, webpack, emblem-loader compiled is not defined

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, karma-runner, webpack, emblem.js

We use coffee-script and emblem for templates in project. Webpack is used for bundling and Karma to run tests. I've tried to use [`emblem-loader`](https://github.com/yoshdog/emblem-loader) for emblem processing with webpack. Here  is the [repository](https://github.com/andrey-dresvyannikov/karma_webpack_emblem-loader/tree/master) I created with simple example how to reproduce it.

karma webpack config (coffee-script):

```
webpack:
      module:
          loaders: [
              { test: /\.coffee$/, loader: "coffee-loader" },
              { test: /\.emblem$/, loader: "emblem-loader"}
          ],
      resolve:
        extensions: ["", ".emblem"]
    webpackMiddleware:
      noInfo: true
```

Template is imported via `emblemTemplate = require 'template_path.emblem'`, then trying to do `emblemTemplate(context)`.

Resulting Errors:

- in PhantomJS: `Can't find variable: compiled`
- in Chrome: `ReferenceError: compiled is not defined`

Definitely the problem is with processing the template and not template itself for loader returns function that check `if (!compiled) {...}`.